# Can we send send data type other than string using node-gcm module?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-gcm

Can we use [node-gcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) to send any data type other than `string` e.g - boolean, I read in their documentation but didn't find anything regarding that?

Or is this the only functionality provided by FCM in `Android` ??

Comment: The FCM API requires that all values are strings.  I don't know what node-gcm does in the middle between your app and the FCM API, but the string requirement doesn't change for FCM.

Comment: @DougStevenson So in FCM API, we cannot send other datatypes?

Comment: The FCM API requires that all values are strings.

Comment: @DougStevenson I never read it anywhere in their docs, can you tell me where it is mentioned? thanks anyways (y)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#resource-message

Comment: Yeah got it, thanks for sharing (y)